# What's the best way to edit Microsoft Word documents on iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, ms-office, webdav, word-processor

I'm on the road and have the need to update my CV which is a Microsoft Word document. My CV is accessible via WebDav but I've also got it stored on the iPad using the Synology DS File app.

What is the best way to edit my CV using the iPad? Is there a native or web based app that can do this for me? I would expect that the formatting and tables in the document to be preserved when it is saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Times have changed since this question was asked. CloudOn has been bought and shut down by DropBox.

Currently, the best way to edit Word documents on iOS is with the [Microsoft Word](https://appsto.re/nz/PWh9I.i) app.

Answer (score 3):

Pages will indeed give you the native app and nice interface, but for *true* Microsoft Word editing, you have to try [CloudOn](http://site.cloudon.com)!

After creating an account in the app on your iPad, you will be given choices to use your dropbox to reach the documents you wish to edit. Another option is to transfer it to the app via iTunes. When editing, you will be using the full version of Microsoft Word on your iPad. No catch. Simply the full version like you know it from your Windows PC desktop. It is amazing!

It takes a while to get used to running it properly on the iPad, but it's worth it when all your CV formatting is intact and editable.

Comment: I gave it a try and it did everything I needed to. It really is a proper version of Word. Impressive.

Comment: I like how it is free too!

Comment: yeah, it is quite amazing really.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Pages](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pages/id361309726?mt=8) to edit Microsoft Word documents on my iPad.

I believe it is $10 via the AppStore.

Pages allows you to open, edit and save back to .DOC, PDF or Pages' native format.

Good luck with the opportunity to present your CV.

Answer (score 1):

I use OnLive Desktop, but in order to access the internet you have to use the 5 dollar premium version. This is the best substitute for writting essays and such using your ipad with the full Microsoft Word program. I have tried CloudOn and I really found it to be difficult because i had to use the monitor keyboard. I also tried Pages but i didn't like not having the look that Microsoft Word offers. So If you want the look and feel of using Microsoft Word you have to give OnLive Desktop a try. I don't mind dishing out 5 bucks a month for it; that is until Office 365 decides to offer Word as some-sort of app!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's online editor is available at [office.com](https://www.office.com).

You can open Word Online directly from [office.live.com/start/Word.aspx](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx).

> Collaborate for free with an online version of Microsoft Word. Save documents in OneDrive. Share them with others and work together at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Google Drive? I'm not sure what kind of content you're editing but Google Drive usually works for me most of the time. To convert a document, right click on it inside Google Drive. Choose Open with → Google Docs. A new window will be opened with the document in Google Docs format and it is saved inside the same folder in your Google Drive.

There is a Google Drive App or you can just access it from safari. I usually like this method better because it's "In the cloud" so the changes I make update everywhere.